# Output the order number in custom WooCommerce thankyou template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, orders

Making a custom thank you page template, I want to display order number if I echo $order = new WC_Order($post_id); it returns values 0 or empty strings: but the permalink has the order id wonder what could be causing this ?

`<strong><?php echo $order = new WC_Order($post_id); echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>`

The whole code is below:

```
<p><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>

<ul class="order_details">
<li class="order">
    <?php _e( 'Order number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    <strong><?php echo $order = new WC_Order($post_id); echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem related to WooCommerce `checkout/thankyou.php` template is:**

- First you can't use **`echo`** with **`$order = new WC_Order($post_id);`** as it's an **object**, but not a string.
- Second, the **`$order`** object already exists in thank you template, so you don't need to get it again. You can see that on your first code line:

```html
<p><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>
```

So your code will be simply:

```
<p><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>

<ul class="order_details">

    <li class="order">
        <?php _e( 'Order number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
    </li>

</ul>
```

This should work…

Comment: I have tried this before as it was my first solution, but it gives me 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_order_number() on string' any ideas ?

Comment: its a new page, wc version 3.1.0. what I did made a new page on settings created php template files and pasted that code in. and did a redirect in functions.php will pasted that below.

Comment: function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;

    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
        $order_key = wc_clean( $_GET['key'] );

        $redirect  = get_permalink (get_page_by_title( "Thank-You" )->ID );
        $redirect .= get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) === '' ? '&' : '?';
        $redirect .= 'order=' . $order_id . '&key=' . $order_key;

        wp_redirect( $redirect );
        exit;
    }
}

Comment: let me know if that helps

Comment: You should better override **existing thankyou template** as you will face some big problems as you can see. If you don't know about **overriding WooCommerce tempates via the theme**, read [**this official short documentation**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) … We don't know why you are making a custom new template, please explain it, updating your question (what are you trying to do and why using this way?)…

Comment: understood, yeah I know how to edit them will do that instead of making new one as it keeps causing problems